# calling a python script from a shell script. Error loading modules

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am running a bash script to run a python script in multiple folders

**the bash script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#$ -S /bin/bash


    ##performs a task on multiple directories contained within current directory

    curdir=$(pwd)
    for folder in /mydir*; do
      [ -d "$folder" ] && cd "$folder" && python mydir/treeCl.py
    done
    cd $curdir
```

**The python script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import treeCl
c = treeCl.Collection(input_dir='input', file_format='fasta', trees_dir='trees')
...
```

**the error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/mydir/treeCl.py", line 2, in <module>
     import treeCl   
File "/mydir/treeCl.py", line 3, in <module>
     c = treeCl.Collection(input_dir='input', file_format='fasta', trees_dir='trees') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Collection'
```

Comment: Don't name your script after the module you are using. That is causing your error.

Comment: That is exactly what happened.